# trouble logging into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am trying to connect to mysql via php using this line

```
  @ $db = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
 exit;
 }
```

I am not getting any response, no error message, nothing.  I even added an `echo'hi';`
after the first line of code and it doesn't show up. When I added `echo'hi';` before the first line hi prints out.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the **new** instead do:

```
 $db = mysqli_connect(...
```

or use new to create a [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php) object

```
 $db = new mysqli(...
```

In the first case $db is assigned the return value of a function. The mysqli_connect function passes back the object created internal to the function. In the second case $db is being created through the new keyword as the result of the "new mysqli(..." expression.

Comment: I tried the first one and I am now getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: @Aaron Do you have mysqli installed? See here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');
```

mysqli_connect is not an object it is function

EDIT:

remove `@`, make sure your `error_reporting( E_ALL );`

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bookorama', 'bookorama123', 'books');
```

"Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()" - do you have mysqli module on ? - Yes in php.ini file.

Comment: Is this the modle?   extension=php_mysqli.dll [PHP_OCI8]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the `@` before function calls. `@` is to suppress any errors from coming up.

Second, remove the `new` keyword. That's for instantiating a new class, not calling a function.